# ORA-20013: DBMS_QOPATCH ran mostly in non install area

Tags: oracle

i'm upgrading a database installation from 12.1 to 18.3 and have hit a problem when running datapatch

[image]

according to this [link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=352113501981222&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2033620.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=nydadz0xf_157) my settings for certain directories are incorrect,  but they look ok to me

[image]

[image]

this is running in centos 7

any ideas what the problem could be?

thanks
dave

Answer (score 0):

the issue was due to a soft link in the ORACLE_HOME and therefore also the paths in the directories for QOPATCH

when replacing the values for ORACLE_HOME and the directory paths to the full path rather than those containing softlinks the issue was resolved